# AWS Lambda Node function timeout occasionally

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a AWS Lambda function written in Node that resizes images when a new image is uploaded to my S3 bucket. The function works flawlessly 99% of the time. It's the 1% that I am wondering about...

On random occasions, the function execution times out at 30 seconds (that's the timeout we have set for our function to run). I don't think upping this timeout is going to save us anything here because it is just flat out hanging.

Below are the logs from CloudWatch. Above the blue line is the failure and 1.5 minutes later (below the blue line) is when it retried and succeeds.

[image: CloudWatch logs]

This is the code that is run in the function, upon uploading of an image to S3.

```
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true }); // Enable ImageMagick integration.
var util = require('util');
var path = require('path');

var MAX_WIDTH = 345;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 345;

// get reference to S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Read options from the event.
    console.log(
        'Reading options from event:\n',
        util.inspect(event, { depth: 5 })
    );
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    var srcKey = decodeURIComponent(
        event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' ')
    );
    var dstBucket = process.env.S3_BUCKET;
    var dstKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.versionId + path.extname(srcKey);
    console.log('Image version: ', dstKey);

    // Sanity check: validate that source and destination are different buckets.
    if (srcBucket == dstBucket) {
        callback('Source and destination buckets are the same.');
        return;
    }

    // Infer the image type.
    var typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
    if (!typeMatch) {
        callback('Could not determine the image type.');
        return;
    }
    var imageType = typeMatch[1];
    if (imageType != 'jpg' && imageType != 'png') {
        callback('Unsupported image type: ${imageType}');
        return;
    }

    // Download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
    async.waterfall(
        [
            function download(next) {
                // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
                s3.getObject(
                    {
                        Bucket: srcBucket,
                        Key: srcKey,
                    },
                    next
                );
            },
            function transform(response, next) {
                gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
                    // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
                    var scalingFactor = Math.min(
                        MAX_WIDTH / size.width,
                        MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
                    );
                    var width = scalingFactor * size.width;
                    var height = scalingFactor * size.height;

                    // Transform the image buffer in memory.
                    this.resize(width, height).toBuffer(imageType, function(
                        err,
                        buffer
                    ) {
                        if (err) {
                            next(err);
                        } else {
                            next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            function upload(contentType, data, next) {
                // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
                s3.putObject(
                    {
                        Bucket: dstBucket,
                        Key: dstKey,
                        Body: data,
                        ContentType: contentType,
                    },
                    next
                );
            },
        ],
        function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(
                    'Unable to resize ' +
                        srcBucket +
                        '/' +
                        srcKey +
                        ' and upload to ' +
                        dstBucket +
                        '/' +
                        dstKey +
                        ' due to an error: ' +
                        err
                );
                callback(err);
            } else {
                console.log(
                    'Successfully resized ' +
                        srcBucket +
                        '/' +
                        srcKey +
                        ' and uploaded to ' +
                        dstBucket +
                        '/' +
                        dstKey
                );
                callback(null, 'Success');
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Are there any settings or ways to avoid these random timeouts? Is this a "boot up" issue where the previous time this function was run was 5 hours prior so it was sitting idle before executing again?

Comment: Hard to tell. I would bet in a combination of "cold start" + "download" + "transform" + "upload", but node.js cold start is extremely fast. I guess if you increase the timeout + memory you could kill the 1% failure, just guessing.

Comment: Even if the execution is a cold start, for a NodeJS function that shouldn't add more than 1 or 2 seconds at the most. Since the retry ran in just over 2 seconds then I wouldn't expect a cold start to take more than 5 seconds. So I don't think that's the issue you are running into here. I would add a lot of logs to your function to try to narrow down exactly what part is hanging. Also, you aren't placing your function inside a VPC are you?

Comment: @MarkB yes the function is running inside a VPC. And that makes sense about the cold start not being the issue, I figured it was a long shot.

Comment: So you're just downloading a file from S3, resizing it, and then uploading it back to S3. Why do you have the function running in a VPC? A Lambda function being in a VPC has no benefit and lots of drawbacks. You should only place a Lambda function in a VPC when you have to access resources inside the VPC (like an EC2 instance or an RDS database for example).

Comment: @MarkB makes sense. I'll see what it will take to get it out of the VPC and see if that improves anything. Thanks for the info!